# Debian 10 PHP not parsing in apache (fresh install)

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.4

I know this is an ancient problem with lots of answers but none of the existing solutions seem to be working.

This is a fresh install of Debian 10, apache2 has been installed and php (7.3).

Apache is not parsing PHP so just displays PHP code as text.

The PHP module is definitely loaded and I have run the following fixes:

```
a2dismod mpm_event && a2enmod mpm_prefork && a2enmod php7.3
```

And also tried:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
​</FilesMatch>
```

In the apache config file. There is a PHP config file that has this covered anyway.

I am not try to run files in the /home directory so is not the default block of that being the problem

I have now removed PHP and Apache and re-installed to get the same problem, rebooted and no further.

I installed PHP with:

```
apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

There are no errors in any logs and I have checked many answers on Stackoverflow with no further clues.

Comment: What is your default php version? You can check it with php -v. Have you tried to display phpinfo output? If not try this: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-create-phpinfo-file

Comment: 7.3 is the PHP version

Comment: Ok. Have you tried that with phpinfo, as I have mentioned before?

Comment: Yes it is is correct. I have found the problem, the site I was testing had a FilesMatch declaration in it's web root folder for PHP FPM handling PHP and HTML files. As FPM was not installed this overwrite did not work, not sure why it wasn't logged though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did solve this by enabling proxy and proxy_fcgi modules

```
a2enmod proxy proxy_fcgi
```

Comment: Please explain how the requests are handled by the PHP-FPM backend.